# FreeForm: Can I make my own template for a user to approve a pending record?

Tags: solspace-freeform

As much as I'd like my user to use the FreeForm Pro Control Panel to approve pending records, I don't want to grant this user access to all of my forms' results. (AFAIK you can't grant access to selected forms--it's either all or none.) So I'm seeing if I can create a template to do this, but I haven't found anything yet in FreeForm's tags. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at these, you can build lists and edit forms in templates with these.

https://solspace.com/docs/freeform/edit/

https://solspace.com/docs/freeform/entries/

Comment: Thanks! Using the freeform:edit tag with the freeform:statuses chunk of code on https://solspace.com/docs/freeform/form/ did the trick.